# Playing Youtube, Vimeo and any other video services' videos in one's own player

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, vimeo

I know Youtube and Vimeo both have embed codes that allow you to embed their player into any webpage. However, I'm looking to build a web player with a consistent appearance. More importantly, I'm looking to build a player that could play videos from as many video hosting services out there. I'm starting with Youtube and Vimeo, but I want to gradually increase the support for video services. I figured that maybe if there was some interface that was consistent between video hosting services, that this maybe easier, like a protocol of some sort. Then it hit me that URLs are the general protocol for this sort of thing; no need to re-invent the protocol. So, if only Youtube and Vimeo provided a URL to a video file that I could play in my player, then I can easily find some cross-section between all these services.

This is why I'm here; I'm asking if anyone knows if these services provide a URL to the raw video file or files (for different formats, flv, H.264, WebM, etc) that I can use for a custom video player? Or is this something the hosting services prohibit due to advertising revenue things?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly programming related. 

Answer (score 3):

It's very unlikely that you'll find a video hosting service that gives you direct access to the files themselves, for many of the reasons you speculate (there's also the issue that they don't want you downloading videos). However, Youtube, at least, offers the ability to embed their video with a chromeless player -- this way, there is no Youtube controls at all so you can overlay your own javascript toolbar, hook it into the player API, etc. Other hosting services also do this.

Vimeo, unless something has changed recently, does have a player API as well, but doesn't give you the options of hiding their controls, so it isn't a perfectly seamless experience.

Here's how you can embed a chromeless player from YouTube:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'voNEBqRZmBc',
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
  });
}
```

You might also find some info by looking at code for players that are already attempting to be wrappers for various video sharing sites, such as http://www.videojs.com

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo allows PRO members to access the source files of any videos they have uploaded via the API.

If this works for you, you can request access to the new API by using the form at https://vimeo.com/help/contact